# Updating radio button method from textchangedevent

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, checked, textchanged

Is it possible to call a radiobutton checked method from a textChanged method for a textbox? I have a group of radio buttons, and when one is selected, it calls the radiobutton_Checked method. This does a calculation and saves the result to a variable called angle_Offset.

I have a textbox whose text is databound to a variable called Heading. This is used in the calculation done in the radiobutton_Checked method.

Right now, the calculation is done whenever a radio button is selected. If I change the text in the textbox, I have to click another radio button to have it update the angle_Offset calculation, but I'm trying to make it so the calculation is done when the text changes without having to select a new radio button (use the current one).

Here's the xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Rotate" Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Heading}" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" />

<RadioButton Content="0°"  Tag="0" GroupName="display" Checked="radiobutton_Checked"/>
<RadioButton Content="90°" Tag="1" GroupName="display" Checked="radiobutton_Checked"/>
<RadioButton Content="180°" Tag="2" GroupName="display" Checked="radiobutton_Checked"/>
<RadioButton Content="270°" Tag="3" GroupName="display" Checked="radiobutton_Checked"/>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
    private int Heading
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(update_Heading); }
        set { SetValue(update_Heading, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty update_Heading = DependencyProperty.Register("Heading", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public void radiobutton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        var tag = Convert.ToInt32(rb.Tag);
        angle_Offset = (degrees_90 * tag) - Heading;
    }

    private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //not sure how to call radiobutton_Checked from here
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to call the radiobutton_Checked method from the textChangedEventHandler, so that the calculation for angle_Offest (found in the radio checked method) using the "Heading" variable is updated. I can't just call it since they have different parameters.

Comment: have you tried just calling the function from the text changed function?  radiobutton_Checked((object)this.myradiobutton, e);

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question. One idiom I've found useful for dealing with radio buttons is to use an `IValueConverter` to map group state to some property value, but it's not really clear from your post exactly how you're using the radio group or what you want the `textChanged()` method to do. My guess is that your problem can be solved without handling either the `TextChanged` event or the `Checked` events, but without a good code example it's not possible to provide specific advice.

Comment: I provided the complete code as asked.

Comment: I second Matt Johnson.  You can call the radioButton_checked method directly, even though it takes different arguments than the textChanged method.  When setting the arguments to the radioButton_checked method, just make sure the sender is the radioButton you need, and it seems the event args can be left as null since it isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the radiobutton Checked event on TextChanged event of the textbox

In you case

```
public void radiobutton_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        var tag = Convert.ToInt32(rb.Tag);
        angle_Offset = (degrees_90 * tag) - Heading;
    }

 protected void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = .. // get the radiobutton checked
        radiobutton_Checked(rb , null);
    }
```